# Is there a xamarin.forms event that indicates when a view has been fully rendered?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a view that has several controls on it - buttons, pictures, tabs, lists, etc. When this view loads, you can see each part of the view being drawn. This effect isn't slow, but it's just slow enough to make the app look slightly clunky when navigating between screens. Is there some way to hide this, and tell the framework to only display the view once all the controls have been fully rendered?

Comment: On the contrary, I believe showing UI instantly and loading its content gradually is more user-friendly, otherwise our app will look less responsive.

Comment: I'm using a loading indicator between screens, so I already have that covered.

Comment: Then, have you tried to load all content in class constructor?

Comment: I tried in the constructor and the OnAppearing event. Result is the same.

Comment: I've never seen this kind of behavior. Do you have some code you could share on how you are doing this?